# After page load, get youtube views for each item

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am using the tablesorter plugin to sort/paginate my portfolio in my dashboard. In each item in my portfolio I have a youtube/vimeo counter that gets the views of the video listed in the portfolio item. Unfortunately, the youtube or vimeo api isn't that quick, thus, the views take about 4 seconds to load for all the items which is before tablesorter kicks in and it is only going to get worse as more items are added.

So I figured I could create a span, with a data id, and use jquery to add the views via ajax it after the page has finished loading. So:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('span.yt_views').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "views.php",
            data: 'yt_views=' + id,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $(this).html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML for each item:

`<span class="yt_views" data-id="<?php echo $row_projects['media_resource_id'] ?>"></span>`

where media resource link is a youtube page with id, so we can send it to `views.php` to get the corresponding view count.

UPDATE: Figure a lot of it out - It seems to be working, but the html content of the span is not getting replaced.

---

Update 2

Doing this seems to work:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('span.yt_views').each(function() {
        var rel = $(this).data('rel');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: 'yt_views=' + rel,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("span[data-id=" + id + "]").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

<span class="yt_views" data-id="<?php echo $row_projects['id']; ?>" data-rel="<?php echo $row_projects['media_resource_link'] ?>"></span>
```

Still not sure why `$(this).html(response);` didn't work replacing the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track. Here are some suggestions...

First of all, the standard way to run `jQuery` on page load looks like this:

```
// your code goes inside a closure to prevent conflicts
// with other js libraries that may be in use
(function($){
    // your code inside here will run
    // when the document loads
})(jQuery);
```

Second, you can loop through the elements with `class="replace"` and set the value as follows:

```
(function($){
    // loop through the elements that have class="replace"
    $('.replace').each(function(i, el){
        $.post('views.php?' + el.data('id'))
         .done(function(response){
            $(el).html(response);
         });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This should work for what you have described, **however** you will be making a separate `AJAX` call for each cell in your table that needs to have the data updated, i.e. another round-trip to the server for each table row. You could increase performance and reduce the load on your server by sending all of the `data-id` values at once and processing them in one function:

```
(function($){
    // first, grab all of the id elements
    var ids = $.map( $(".replace"), function(span) { return $(span).data("id"); });
    // then make one AJAX call to get all of the view counts
    $.post( "views.php?ids=" + ids )
     .done( function(response){
        // assuming the AJAX call returned an associative
        // array that looks something like response[data-id] = count
        $(response).each(function(id,count){
            $('.replace[data-id="' + id + '"]').html(count);
        });
     });
})(jQuery);
```

For this second method to work, your PHP would have to look something like:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json');
    $ids = $_POST['ids'];
    $counts = array();
    foreach( $ids as $id ) {
        // make the API call that gets the view count...
        $counts[id] = /* value returned by API call */;
    }

    echo json_encode($counts);
```

Hope this helps. I didn't test this code, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. I think I'll got the assoc array route

Comment: But one thing, I wanted this to run AFTER the page loads, I read that the bind way of doing it was right for this kindof thing.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right. I'd try it both ways and see if there's any difference. The only difference would be to put the code I wrote inside of the `$(window).bind()` function.

Comment: I'm trying to get your second method to work but am having trouble. The post keeps sending it to `views.php?ids=[object%20Object]` and thus the php is returning null

Comment: I think I did it slightly wrong. I've updated the line that grabs the ids and puts them into an array. The problem was that the [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function was returning an `object` instead of an `array`.

Comment: One last question I get an array like this from the request `{"251275920":"469","78361702":"46551","160511883":"26771","63625339":"366","230842160":"379"}` how do I get that to integrate properly here `$('.replace[data-id="' + id + '"]').html(count);` it gives me an unrecognized expression

Comment: I am using a php function exact to yours:  `$ids = explode(',', $_GET['yt_viewss']);
    $counts = array();
    foreach($ids as $id) {
  $q = Nemesis::select("media_resource_link", "projects", "id=" . $id);
  list($media_resource_link) = $q->fetch_row();
  if (!empty($media_resource_link)) {
   $yt = Media_Resource::getMediaResourceViews($media_resource_link);
   $counts[$id] =  $yt;
  }
 }
 echo json_encode($counts);`

Comment: The [`$.each( function( id, count ){...})`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function parameters should automatically be set to the key/value pairs that get sent back to you in the response. In other words, on each iteration, `id` should be set to a value like `251275920, 78361702, 160511883` etc., and `count` should be set to the corresponding value for that, e.g. `469, 46551, 26771` etc. So `$('.replace[data-id="' + id + '"]')` searches for all elements that have a `data-id` attribute that is equal to the specific value that is getting passed in.

Comment: the format you put in your comment that starts "One last question..." should be correct